# Connect directly to SSH tunnel without having to first connect to server?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, port, tunnel

I just setup my Raspberry Pi to create a remote SSH tunnel with a VPS I have.  It works, so from my computer I ssh into my VPS (with something like 'ssh user@vps.com', and once connected to that I ssh into the tunnel (with something like 'ssh -p 2222 pi@localhost' and it works.  My question is, is there any way I can make it so I can directly connect to the tunnel on port 2222 (or any other port) without having to login to the VPS?

So instead of having 2 steps, I simply connect from my computer to the tunnel (with something like 'ssh -p 2222 pi@vps.com'

Answer (score 1):

Here is a look at how my config looks.. This can give you an idea as to how to create a tunnel. But To answer your question, there is a way. Using an /.ssh/config will get you there:

```
Host *
        StrictHostKeyChecking no

Host server_one 
        ForwardAgent yes
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        User foo
        HostName %h.bar.net

Host server_two
        ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p server_one nc 2> /dev/null
        User foo
        HostName %h.foo.net 
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Using ProxyCommand will be the trick:

ProxyCommand ssh -q -W pi@vps.com:2222 -w 2222:2222 localhost

I will try that and take a look at [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)

Answer (score 0):

I can make this work if do  `ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 root@example.com` on my client.

And now i can do `ssh -p 2222 clientUser@example.com`

Answer (score 0):

If the tunnel is already up and not part of this question:

```
ssh -J user@vps.com -p 2222 pi@localhost
```

Or add this to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host raspi
  User pi
  Hostname localhost
  Port 2222
  ProxyJump user@vps.com
```

Then:

```
ssh raspi
```